# Problems with numpy importation

Tags: numpy

I´m trying to work with numpy and scipy but I´m unable. In the begining I had another error, right now if I write `import numpy as np` I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/num.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:/Python34\numpy.py", line 2, in <module>
    a = np.arange(10)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'arange'
```

I had wroten `a=...` before. Does someone have any idea? Both `numpy` and `scipy` are already installed into the lib of my `python 3.4`

Comment: show us your code that has the `import numpy as np` in it.

Comment: you write `import numpy` not `import numpy as np`

Comment: .. did you happen to name your *own* module `numpy.py`?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you `import numpy as np`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> print a
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```